# has anyone found a reasonable way to move will_paginate stuff into a model in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, will-paginate

Trying to use the will_paginate gem in rails 3, and I want to move as much of this business into the model as possible, however it seems difficult, and I haven't seen much on it. Usually, you would do something like:

```
Resource.where(:foo => :bar).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Is there anyway to get that `params[:page]` into the model?  `params` isn't accessible there. My ideal would be to somehow work this into a `scope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params are available in a method of a model if the method takes the params as a parameter and the params are passed to the model by the controller. However, it would be better to pass only the params[:page], because the model *should* not know anything about the params. See, for instance, [this example](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Simple-search).

Pagination is mostly not business logic: it's about how you present the data. Hence most code involved does not belong in a model. However, will_paginate provides convenience methods to obtain results 0-15, 15-30, ... of a model and coughing up those lists is simply an ability of an activerecord model, which is why it does belong there.